# I made a pull request from my master branch. Now that request is pending and I want to submit another request

Tags: git, github, version-control

So, I'm new to Git and Github.

I'm contributing to this project and I fixed an issue.

I wasn't aware that I shouldn't make a pull request from master branch.
Now my pull request is pending. And I want to make another pull request of some other issue.

This is what I did.

Pushed changes to master branch and made a pull request. Now my forked repo is one commit ahead of original.

I fixed another issue and pushed changes to master branch. After doing this I realized that something is wrong. My repo was now 2 commits ahead of the original. I thought you could send pull requests for individual commits but you can't do that.

```
git push -f origin HEAD^:master
```

I used that to undo the changes. Now my repo is one commit ahead of the original. I created another branch for that particular issue.

My question is how can I remove that one commit I made to master branch in the new branch I've just created and then push the changes I undo'd before in this new branch.

Right now my changes are commit and waiting to be pushed (new issue). If I could just bring it back to unstage state I can then remove my 1st commit using `git push -f origin HEAD^:<new branch>` and then commit to it.

I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 3):

#### Fixing your pull request

Are you sure that nobody else has reviewed the changes in the pull request with the unintended commit?
If you're sure, then you can force-push `HEAD^` of your local `master` to your GitHub `master`, they way you yourself found:

```
git push -f origin HEAD^:master
```

This will effectively remove the unintended commit from the pull request.

If somebody has already reviewed the changes in your pull request,
then none of this might matter.
(Perhaps an apology is due for the mess.)

#### Creating another pull request

Ideally,
a new pull request should use a branch that is based on the latest version of the remote master,
not including your changes pending in your first pull request.
This is how you should create a new branch before working on a second pull request:

```
git fetch upstream  # assuming that "upstream" is the repo of the project maintainers
git checkout -b next-feature upstream/master
# hack hack hack
git commit -m 'hack hack hack'
git push -u origin HEAD
# -> Go to GitHub and create the pull request
```

If your next feature depends on the pending pull request,
then it's ok to create a new branch from the current one,
instead of a new copy of `upstream/master`.
However, in this case,
don't create the pull request before the previous one is accepted.
If you do so,
and somebody reviews the 2nd pull request before the 1st one,
he will see all changes that you did in both the 1st and 2nd pull request,
which can be confusing.
Wait until the 1st one is accepted, and create the 2nd one after.

Answer (score 0):

Pull requests work on branches, and include all commits that are on that branch but not on the target branch you are submitting your pull request to.

In order to submit a second, independent pull request, just create a new branch off the original base commit (i.e. the upstream master), push that new branch, and submit a pull request from that new branch targetting the same master.

So if your first pull request just contains one commit, you could do the following:

```
# create a new branch used for the first pull request
git branch pull_request_1

# reset `master` so it points to the commit before your PR
git reset --hard HEAD~1

# create and checkout a new branch for your new pull request
git checkout -b pull_request_2

# do work and commit
git commit …

# push the new branch
git push origin pull_request_2
```

Now, you could also push the `pull_request_1` branch, and force-push your fork’s `master` so it matches the upstream branch again but since your first pull request references your `master` branch and not the then non-existing `pull_request_1` branch, this would affect your pull request. So the best option is just to wait until the first pull request is resolved. For the future though, you should always consider creating a new branch for every pull request you create, so you don’t mix up the commits that are actually part of the upstream repository, and your own commits that you want to submit independently.